# Excel search in Array and return column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to use a value to search a range of rows. Then I need to return a column from that row.

I've been looking into `VLOOKUP`, but the result has to be within the range, so I don't know how to go from there.

I already managed to check if Sheet 2 A is in sheet 1 A range with the following:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A600;Sheet1!A2)
```

I Would like in sheet 2, in column B, to check if column A is anywhere in sheet 1 column A. If it is, return the matched row and return the column C.

How would I get this?

**Sheet 1:**

[image]

**sheet 2:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use VLookup

The formula for VLOOKUP is

```
=VLOOKUP(search_key,range,column_index,is_sorted)
```

So in your case, just make sure the range covered all column in sheet1, not just the column A. Column_index will be the index of the column where we look up the value (start from 1), And also is_sorted to be false so the range will not change because of sorting. The formula could be like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:C6,3,false)
```

Hope that helps